# Java use http proxy for https traffic

Tags: java, proxy

I have a problem with making a Java process use the proxy in my organisation.
I read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) carefully but still not can make it work.
I assume it might be a problem with a mix-up between http and https:

My organisation offers *only* an http proxy. Therefore, in the OS of my machine both `export http_proxy` and `export https_proxy` return `http://proxy.myorg.org` (no `https://`).
Is there a way to tell Java to use a proxy for https-connections, but to connect with http to the proxy?
If I understand correctly, `https.proxyHost` expects the server name but no protocol to it.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out I did a formatting error in my Java systm properties. The usage of the http proxy for https traffic works with `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.myorg.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.myorg.org -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080`